# TypeError: Error #1009

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a document class, and this Enemy class. I have a function to MAKE the enemies in the document class. In this Enemy class, I'm hitTesting for Bullets (Kogel), and if the enemy is off the stage. In both, i'm remove the child. And it works. But it gives me this TypeError #1009. This is the enemy code, where both the "remove off of stage" and "kogel hitTest" are. (i also have the same problem with the ship, but that's for another time. I think i can work that out when i work out this.)

```
package 
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.*;
import amateurodius;
import flash.display.Stage;

public class vijandEen extends MovieClip
{
    var speed:int = 8;
    var theHero:ruimteschip;
    var schot:Bullet;

    public function vijandEen(aSchip:ruimteschip, Kogel:Bullet)
    {
        theHero = aSchip;
        schot = Kogel;
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, vijandBewegen);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collissionSchip);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collissionKogel);
    }

     function vijandBewegen(e:Event)
    {
        x +=  speed;
        if (this.x > stage.stageWidth)
        {
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }

     function collissionSchip(e:Event)
    {
        if (theHero.hitTestObject(this))
        {
            trace("geraakt...");
            verwijderSchip(e);

        }
    }

     function collissionKogel(e:Event)
    {
        if (schot.hitTestObject(this))
        {
            trace('raak!');
            verwijderEnemy(e);
        }
    }

    function verwijderEnemy(e:Event){
        if (this.parent != null){
            this.parent.removeChild(this);
        }
    }

    function verwijderSchip(e:Event){
        if (this.parent != null){
            theHero.parent.removeChild(theHero);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Edit - Here's my document class code:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.ui.Mouse;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.media.Sound;

public class amateurodius extends MovieClip
{
    public var schip:ruimteschip = new ruimteschip();
    public var Kogel = new Bullet();
    var sound = new lazor();
    var BGM = new Muziek();
    var backdrop = new background();
    var shootAllow:Boolean = true;
    var enemyTime:int = 0;
    var enemyLimit:int = 50;

    public function amateurodius()
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, initialize);
    }

    function initialize(e:Event)
    {
        addChild(backdrop);
        addChild(schip);
        BGM.play();
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, vijandmaken);
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, spawnKogel);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, kogelCheck);
        Mouse.hide();
    }

    public function vijandmaken(e:Event)
    {
        if (enemyTime < enemyLimit)
        {
            enemyTime++;
        }
        else
        {
            var newEnemy = new vijandEen(schip,Kogel);
            newEnemy.x = -1 * newEnemy.width;
            newEnemy.y = int(Math.random()*(stage.stageHeight - newEnemy.height));
            addChild(newEnemy);
            enemyTime = 0;
        }
    }

    public function spawnKogel(e:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
        if (shootAllow == true)
        {
            if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.SPACE)
            {
                addChild(Kogel);
                Kogel.x = schip.x;
                Kogel.y = schip.y;
                sound.play();
                shootAllow = false;
                kogelCheck(e);
            }
        }
    }

    function kogelCheck(e:Event)
    {
        if (Kogel.x < -30)
        {
            shootAllow = true;
        }
        else
        {
            shootAllow = false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: When debugging, it points at this line as the problem, in the function vijandBewegen:

if (this.x > stage.stageWidth)

Comment: i pinpointed it. It that one "this" right there... and i'm not really sure how to solve it...

Comment: alrighty, just tried to remove that "this" and it still gives me the error...

Comment: are you sure it's not the stage?

Comment: It probably is. And i'm scouring the internet for solutions to load the stage before doing anything else, but none work...

Comment: have you added it to the stage? it automatically gets the reference when you do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private function stopEvents():void
{
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, vijandBewegen);
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collissionSchip);
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collissionKogel);
}
function vijandBewegen(e:Event)
{
    x +=  speed;
    if (this.x > stage.stageWidth)
    {
        stopEvents();
        this.parent.removeChild(this);
    }
}

function verwijderEnemy(e:Event)
{
    if (this.parent != null)
    {
        stopEvents();
        this.parent.removeChild(this); 
    }
}
```

I think your code keeps checking every frame but you lose reference to the stage when you remove it, so it has no idea what stage is ( == `null` ). This can happen any time you remove it from the stage.

edit: i jsut realised something else, you should not initialize event listeners that deal with the stage until you've added your object to the stage. ie:

```
public function vijandEen(aSchip:ruimteschip, Kogel:Bullet)
{
    theHero = aSchip;
    schot = Kogel;
    this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, function (e:Event)
    {
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, vijandBewegen);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collissionSchip);
        addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, collissionKogel);
     });
 }
```

Also as a sidenote, you should not use Capital first letters as variable names, keep them for Class names. Same goes for lowercase first letters, they should be kept for vars.

Comment: Same goes for every function where you remove it from the stage, i'm guessing you keep a pointer to this object somewhere so Flash doesn't garbage collect it.

Comment: alright, i put the document class code into the original post, too.

I'm sorry though, this is my first programming assignment, ever. So it's kinda hard for me to pinpoint faults sometimes.

Comment: that's alright, have you tried my post? does it work?

Comment: if it doesn't work, please add `trace(stage)` before the conditional, i'm curious when it starts saying null (if that's even the problem)

Comment: hmm, it seems the moment the bullet collides with the enemy, stage gets 'null'. so the problem might be at function collissionKogel, which sees if the bullet hits the enemy.